# Accessing a local instance of the bot framework using DirectLine

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a bot (basically a clone of the echo bot) and I'm running the service locally.  Is it possible to use the Direct Line API to access it (I'm using the NuGet package: Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine), and I'm trying to access it like this:

```
DirectLineClient client = new DirectLineClient();
client.BaseUri = new Uri($"http://localhost:3978/api/messages");

var conversation = await client.Conversations.StartConversationAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, `conversation` is always null.  Is it possible to connect to the service locally, or does it have to be deployed to Azure?  If the former, then what could I be doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, in order to use directline, you have to have at least a bot channels registration to get the direct line secret. That being said, there is a offline-directline node package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-directline). I'll see if there's a C# equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The Offline-directline package is a way to set up a node server and use directline/webchat to connect to it as if it were a azure endpoint.

You're basically going to follow the [usage instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-directline#usage) as they're laid out:

1) Install offline-directline (OD) package

2) Create the OD server using node

3) Run your bot

4) Connect to your bot through a custom webchat that looks to the OD server from step 2 instead of localhost or an azure endpoint

Comment: I executed the first 3 steps. I have my bot running on http://localhost:8080/api/messages. It works well on the bot emulator. I installed the directline package too and have it running on port 3000. I coded the webchat client as this - https://pastebin.com/q4cSekCd. I get an error on the console as -utility_all2.js:13624 Uncaught ReferenceError: getProd is not defined
    at utility_all2.js:13624
Can you guide me on what could be wrong?